# Can't get ellipsis to work on Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a TextView. I want it to ellipsize if longer than its available width. This does not work unless the input string has no spaces... can anyone provide an example of this working? I've tried different combinations of:

singleLine="true"
 maxLines="1"
 scrollHorizontally="false"

none of these have any effect. Again, if I supply a string that has no spaces in it, then the ellipsis appears correctly. What am I missing? I've tried this on 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, all same problem.

Thanks

Comment: A quick and hacky solution might be to display your string using non-breaking spaces instead of the regular spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ellipsize is broken (go [vote on the bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882), especially since they claim it's not reproducible) so you have to use a minor hack. Use:

```
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
```

on anything you want to ellipsize. Also, don't use `singleLine`, it's been deprecated since 1.5.

Comment: @fiXedd: except that your method doesn't work - as per your link and BGS's comment, what works for me is comment #9: 

Try to use android:lines="1" and android:scrollHorizontally="true" instead of 
android:singleLine="true"_

Comment: For TextView's, `android:ellipsize="end"` combined with `android:maxLines="1"` works great !

Comment: This way I get spell-check on textView's. Which looks strange and makes my big ass listview laggy. So it left me no other choise than using `android:singleLine="true"`.

Answer (score 11):

this was the only combination that I could get to work on SDK ver4:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

(Yes I know it says it's deprecated but I'm left without a choice)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
textView.setSingleLine();
TruncateAt truncate = TruncateAt.END;
textView.setEllipsize(truncate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution.

```
int limit = 9;
if (str.length() > limit) {
    textView.setText(str.substring(0, limit)+"...");
} else {
    textView.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: No combination of the xml properties worked for me. To save time and to know 100% what I'm going to get on whatever OS I went with this. Thanks.

Comment: That summarizes the Android Development experience in general