# How to abbreviate a TextView?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a TextView that is a single line. How can I add ellipses (...) if the text is too long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your XML-file you can use: `android:ellipsize="end"`.

In your .java code you can use:
    `yourTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.valueOf("END"));`.

Remember to use it when you want ellipses if the text is reaching its parent's width.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of some issues by using the function: [Android: Something better than android:ellipsize="end" to add "..." to truncated long Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769105/android-something-better-than-androidellipsizeend-to-add-to-truncated)

however, its still the most robust way to do it.