# TextView ellipsize style on Android

Tags: android, textview

I use below layout.xml to show ellipsize:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

And it can show ellipsize in TextView success.
But the ellipsize style in some devices only show one ".".
Such as below picture between M and k:
[image]
And some devices can show "...".
Such as below picture between J and p:
[image]
I want to let all devices show as style 2.
How can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use `&#8230;` which represents ellipsize, it should work.

So for your example, it would be...

```
ABCDEFGHIJ&#8230;PQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Give it a go.

Comment: You mean replace string to &#8230;?

Comment: But if in different devices, there are may different width and can show string length are different.

Comment: @brian, how you are setting the TextView with strings before and after? Also, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769105/android-something-better-than-androidellipsize-end-to-add-to-truncated)...

Comment: I only setText("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");.

Comment: Ok. I just tried your code by setting the text to `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and `...` shows up correctly. I also added `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` and it seemed to work. Try adding `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` and see if that makes a difference in the devices it does not work.

Comment: I try add android:scrollHorizontally="true", it still the same.

Comment: I think the ellipsize is work. But it only show ".", but not "...". Is it possible modify?

Comment: No @brian, I've run out of ideas. From what I understand, the ellipsize does not change the text but only displays `...` where ever we need it so don't think we can modify it. The docs say `You will often also want to set scrollHorizontally or singleLine as well so that the text as a whole is also constrained to a single line instead of still allowed to be broken onto multiple lines.`. We have tried both `scrollHorizontally or singleLine`. Which device are you testing on?

Comment: I test on device ASUS TF201.

Comment: Have a look at [this bug logged](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33868). It might be relating to this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `android:singleLine="true"`.You can use `android:maxLines="1"` .It's awsome